# Find the equation of a line which passes through point A(1,0,-1) and is perpendicular to straight lines.....

Tags: vectors

Question :

Find the equation of a line which passes through point A(1,0,-1) and is perpendicular to straight lines $\vec{r} =2 \hat{i}-\hat{j}+\hat{k}+\lambda (2\hat{i}+7\hat{j}-3\hat{k}) $ and $\vec{r} =3\hat{i}-\hat{j}+3\hat{k}+\lambda (2\hat{i}-2\hat{j}+5\hat{k})$

It is given in solution :

Since the line to be determined is perpendicular to the given two straight lines, it is directed towards the vector, ( why so ? )

Can somebody explain one the above statement it will be of great help to me Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let  Direction Cosine of that line be $<a,b,c>\;,$ Then equation of line which passess through

$(1,0,1)$ is $\displaystyle \frac{x-1}{a}=\frac{y-0}{b}=\frac{z-1}{c}.......(1)$

Now above line be Perpendicular to $\vec{r} =2 \hat{i}-\hat{j}+\hat{k}+\lambda (2\hat{i}+7\hat{j}-3\hat{k})$.

So Direction cosine of that line be $<2,7,-3>$

So Dot product of these line be $0.$ So we get $2a+7b-3c=0...............(2)$

Similarly $\vec{r} =3\hat{i}-\hat{j}+3\hat{k}+\lambda (2\hat{i}-2\hat{j}+5\hat{k})$

So Direction of that line be $<2,-2,5>$

So Dot product of $(1)$ line be $2a-2b+5b=0........................................(3)$

Now calculate values of $a,b,c$ from these two equation. and put into $(1).$

Comment: why we have  $\frac{z-1}{0}$ ?

Comment: Sorry Nazir I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I think to find such st line you need a directing vector and using the point you have , you will find its parametric equqtion.

To find its directing vector, which is perpendicular to the directing vectors of the two given lines,  you may  try the cros product of these two given directed vectors .